# Looking for a Short Story about a Space Prison with simulated unending torture

Tags: story-identification

A few years ago I read in a science fiction magazine from the 1990's a short story about a Jail put on a spaceship, where the worst scum of the universe was put to repent of their crimes. The story was told from the perspective of the warden, who was forced to come up with new punishment for each prisoner as they were all frozen and put in a simulated world.
Could anyone help me find this?

Comment: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/prisons

Comment: Can you perhaps give some examples of the plot? Examples of the tortures administered? Names of characters?

Comment: Sure, I remember one of the detainees was an artist that had put a poison in a planet's water supply that made everyone claw out their eyes. Her punishment was, in her own "dreamworld" she would see people using her art as kindling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it, sorry to take space. The short story is ["The Cold Cage"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47583) by Ray Aldridge published in February 1990 by "Fantasy&Science Fiction". [The issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?FSFFEB90)

The [cover art](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/4/4b/FSFFEB90.jpg) is pretty memorable, the period fits (february 1990) and I remember that it was this magazine.

Comment: Self-answering is perfectly acceptable. Can you please indicate how this story matches your recollections.

Comment: Well I don't actually have the funds on my paypal to pay for the issue and I can't seem to find a text online but I will definitely put it up when I read it again.

Comment: Also I could not find a reference in the wiki page you linked but I will withhold any edits until I read the story again.

Comment: So, what makes you feel this is the right answer? :) And you should be able to accept your answer in about 44 hours.

Comment: The [cover art](https://36.media.tumblr.com/6e2bb66eecc9e8d4bcc711ec7c661c30/tumblr_n9hh37ZwNP1rv0p43o1_500.jpg) is pretty memorable, the period fits (february 1990) and  I remember that it was this magazine.